# How to add pins to the google maps geocode api

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to combine these three things into one.

- http://jsfiddle.net/Dansker/hk5fgbzr/3/ (fiddle 1)
- http://jsfiddle.net/Dansker/rnrba8so/10/ (fiddle 2)
- data.illinois.gov/resource/wsms-teqm.json (data source)

I want to add pins like I did in fiddle 1 two the code I have in fiddle 2. However I need to use the data different data source. The way I made it work in fiddle 1 was with the latitude and longitude. But because I can not do that with the new data source I need to find a new way. That is why I am trying to add it to fiddle one. Will that work? If so how can I do it? If it wont work what would you suggest using the google maps api?

```
$.getJSON(URL, function(data, textstatus) {

          $.each(data, function(i, entry) {

              var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + entry.name_ + " Library" + '</h1>'+ '<hr>' + 
                  '<div id="bodyContent">'+ 
                  '<p>' + entry.address + " " + entry.zip + '.<br>' + 
                  '<p>' + '<a href="'+entry.website.url+'">' + entry.website.url + '</a>' + '</p>'+
                  '<p>' + entry.hours_of_operation + '</p>'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '</div>';


              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: contentString
              });


              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(entry.location.latitude, 
                                                   entry.location.longitude),
                  map: map,
                  title: entry["dba_name"] + "\n" + entry["address"]
              });

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
              });

          });
    });
```

Comment: The geocoder will only work for ~10-20 points before hitting the query limit. For 212 addresses, it will be prohibitively slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 2 callback functions, the correct way to do this is to first finish work for first callback, in this case, downloading the JSON and parse them, also I would store all the `entry` into `entries` just so that we can use the data when we add the markers, which is called at the end of the first callback.

about the API access limit, sadly I think you have to use the paid google maps geocoding API, or other services like openStreetmaps.

I also have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kylelam/wakx5cpg/1/) setup, hope this help.